# Data distribution in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to spark and have general question.As far as I know the whole file must be available on all worker nodes to be processed.If so, how do they know which partition should read?Driver controls the partitions but how does driver tell them to read what partition?

Answer (score 0):

Each RDD is divided into multiple partition. To compute each partition, Spark will generate a task and assign it to a worker node. When the driver sends a task to the worker, it also specifies the PartitionID of that task.

The worker then executes the task by chaining the RDD's iterator all the way back to the InputRDD and pass along the PartitionID. The InputRDD determines which part of the input corresponding to the specified partition id and return the data.

```
rddIter.next -> parentRDDIter.next -> grandParentRDDIter.next -> ... -> InputRDDIter.next
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark tries to read data into an RDD from the nodes that are close to it. Since Spark usually accesses distributed partitioned data, to optimize transformation operations it creates partitions to hold the data chunks.

[image]

https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark-book

Comment: Do you mean that workers first fetch all their partitions and then process them?